# Files testing in linux by using if condition

Tags: linux, bash

In bash Scripting, can u explain this if statement `if[ -d "/"$file ]` thus it will check it is a directory? where `$file` is a variable which stores the `ls /`

Comment: Add your script to your question.

Comment: The space between `if` and `[` isn't optional.

Comment: The best way to understand such things is to read the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ -d "/"$file ]
```

is a same as

```
test -d "/"$file
if (exit $?)
```

or

```
if $(test -d "/"$file)
```

and test -d FILE mean :FILE exists and is a directory (man test).

because inside test.c you have :

```
case 'd':                   /* File is a directory? */
  return (sh_stat (arg, &stat_buf) == 0 && (S_ISDIR (stat_buf.st_mode)));


 sh_stat        to have stat_buf of the FILE, if exist.
 S_ISDIR        mask on stat_buf to know if it is a directory.
```

Why double quotes in if statement :

```
to concat string "A" and "B" you can write "A""B"
to concat "/" and $file you can write "/"$file , "/"${file}, "/$file" or "/${file}"
```

Comment: can u explain why double quotes in if statement?

Comment: `test` is also a Bash built-in and will be run instead of `/bin/test`, so the relevant source in this case would be Bash itself, I'd say.

Comment: if [ -d $file ] is same as if [ -d "/"$file ] ?

Comment: @chandu if [ -d $file ] and if [ -d "/"$file ] are not the same , but they can give the same result if $file begin with /. Try ls //bin and ls /bin.